# Incorrect Boot Camp Delete

Tags: hard-drive, windows, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I tried to remove some space from the Boot Camp partition and return it to the Mac partition using [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com). It required me to restart my Mac to have it work (MiniTool Partition Wizard is in Boot Camp).

Once I reloaded, it showed an error, so I thought I may have taken away too much from Boot Camp, making it not able to show, so I just went into Mac, opened Disk Utility, and took away all of the space from Boot Camp and gave it all to Mac.

After that, I want to reinstall Boot Camp but the software would be stuck in the Install screen, not really loading:

[image: Bootcamp assistant]

I checked holding <kbd>Option</kbd> while opening my Mac, and it still shows Windows, however, when I click into it, it just shows an error screen. I have also tried using terminal `diskutil list` but couldn't find the microsoft disk.

Any input would be helpful.

Comment: I don't see any sign that MiniTool Partition Wizard knows how to work with macOS (APFS) partitions. Windows partitioning tools sometimes mess up the macOS partition because they don't understand it, so I recommend avoiding them for Boot Camp setups. (I also recommend having a backup of anything you care about -- this is a good general policy, but especially important when doing anything like repartitioning.)

Answer (score 0):

The posted image shows the Boot Camp Assistant is stuck at the step where the Windows Support Software should be downloading from Apple. Sometimes the download can take a while to complete. Other times, there can be problems, with the connection or Apple servers, resulting in being stuck at this step. You may be able to solve the problem by trying again later.

Using the Disk Utility to remove the Windows partition does not necessarily remove the Windows boot code. Therefore, the option to select Windows may still appear when *"holding Option while opening my Mac"*.